# Grails framework method addTo throws exception on multiple invoke

Tags: java, database, grails, groovy

I want to add subscriptions to a User class, I do it by invoking the "addTo" method, here is my code:

```
if (params.jobs == "on") {
        user.addToSubscriptions(Category.findWhere(id: 1L))
    } else {
        user.removeFromSubscriptions(Category.findWhere(id: 1L))
    }
```

The "params" come from checkboxes, where the user can subscribe to a category by setting checkboxes. The code above is invoked when a form is submitted. What doesn't work is when the user changes more than 1 categories, think of the same code as above with different params.x, like this

```
    if (params.offers == "on") {
        Category cat = Category.get(2)
        if (!user.subscriptions.contains(cat))
        user.addToSubscriptions(Category.findWhere(id: 2L))//needs long variable
    } else {
        user.removeFromSubscriptions(Category.findWhere(id: 2L))
    }
```

What also happens only the category which is first in the code gets added and removed, all other throw the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

edit:
the line in which the exception is thrown is this one though, which makes no sense to me

edit:
The exception gets thrown when I want to add a category, which is already added, it also doesn't get removed. (That's only for the categories which are not handled first in the code, don't ask me why)

```
     //reload page
    redirect(action: "userSettings")
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you are trying to remove a category which is not associated with user?
Like you know... user has no Category with id = 2 and he sent params.offers == "off" ?

Maybe you should do something like:

```
if (params.jobs == "on") {
    user.addToSubscriptions(Category.findWhere(id: 1L))
} else {
    Category cat = Category.get(2L)
    if (user.subscriptions.contains(cat)) {
        user.removeFromSubscriptions(cat)
    }
}
```

Few tips:
If you have id, don't use:

```
Category.findWhere(id:1L)
```

but:

```
Category.get(1L)
```

The error is thrown on the line you pasted, because it is probably last line of your controller, thus after this line yout transaction is committed where the error is thrown.

Try adding this code to your controller:

```
user.save()
user.errors?.allErrors?.each { println it }
```

this will print all errors which happened during save.

Comment: hmm thank you, but it didnt help. The problem is the exception gets only thrown when I want to add it and its already added. But I check with your method if (!user.subscriptions.contains(cat)), it still gets thrown. For all Categories but the one who gets handled first in the code, its not possible to remove the category, I print the user.subscriptions in the console. This didnt help sadly.

Comment: i gave you an upvote because with this if (user.subscriptions.contains(cat) I could fix another problem I didnt mention here :) sadly the subscription thing still doesnt work

Comment: have you tried printing errors? Could you paste them here? I can see you've edited code sample in your question, but you forgot to edit the else clause. It seems quite important.

Comment: sure, no problem! 2011-07-21 16:42:10,251 [http-8080-4] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - failed batch ///
2011-07-21 16:42:10,253 [http-8080-4] ERROR events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session ///

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update /// 2011-07-21 16:42:10,262 [http-8080-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [POST] / ///  ava.sql.BatchUpdateException: failed batch     these are the errors and exceptions when I try to add a category twice (except for the first one in code) sorry if its not good readable, in this text field, line breaks are not possible

Comment: What I meant asking for errors was the code I gave you with if (!user.save()) user.errors.allErrors.each { println it}

Comment: hmm I did it and backchecked it, these are all the errors and exception the console tells me, apart from all the "at org..." descirptions.

Comment: hmmm I might have put it all wrong. I'will edit my answer with a little bit different code

Comment: I tryed this too, it doesnt show more errors, I placed the code right above the redirect, so it should be executed

Comment: `user.subscriptions.contains(cat)` might not work if you don't have a proper `equals/haschCode` defined in `Category`.

Comment: If you are still facing this issue I think you should go back to basics and start testing some scenarios: check if a user can add two subscriptions [in a test, not through your code]. Then check what happens when user tries to remove a category not in the list. Then check adding a new category and removing something not on the list. Use a test suite rather than your code. Try to get the same error you are getting from your code. There is one more thing that came to my mind. You are always removing a category with certain ID. Don't you have two way association between Category and User?